# TypeScript Field Type Dependent on Other Field

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

```
type Formula =
  | {
      fn: (a: number) => number;
      arg: number;
    }
  | {
      fn: (a: () => number) => number;
      arg: () => number;
    };
```

In this example, how can I type Formula so that `fn` always accepts `arg` as a parameter?  I still need something like the `Formula` type to represent both kinds of formulas in case I want to mix them in a list or create a function that can return either type.

```
formula1.fn(formula1.arg) // should always work.
```

In other words:

1. If `arg` is a `number`, `fn` should be a `(number) => number`
2. If `arg` is a `() => number`, `fn` should be a `(() => number) => number`
3. There exists one type which covers both types of formula.

```
// Just applies formula.fn to formula.arg
const calc = (
  formula: Formula
) => formula.fn(formula.arg);  // formula.arg fails to type check

/*
Argument of type 'number | (() => number)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & (() => number)'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number & (() => number)'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => number'.ts(2345)
*/


// Should succeed (fn takes a number and arg is a number)
const num1 = calc({
  fn: (a) => a + 1,
  arg: 3
})

// Should succeed (fn takes a () => number and arg is a () => number)
const num2 = calc({
  fn: (a) => a() + 1,
  arg: () => 3
})

// Should fail because arg is a number and fn expects a () => number parameter
const num3 = calc({
  fn: (a) => a() + 1,
  arg: 4
})

// Should fail because arg is a () => number and fn expects a number parameter
const num4 = calc({
  fn: (a) => a + 1,
  arg: () => 4
})

// It should be possible to build an array
// containing types of formulas.
const formulas: Formula = [
   // plain number formula
  {
    fn: a => a + 3,
    arg: 4
  },
   // () => number formula
  {
    fn: a => a() * 2,
    arg: () => 11
  }
]

const answers = formulas.map(calc)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a generic function.

```
type Formula = {
   fn: <T extends (() => number) | number>(a: T) => number;
}
```

Or, maybe you would prefer the second one:

```
type Formula<Arg> = {
      fn: (a: Arg) => number;
      arg: Arg
}

const calc = <T extends (() => number) | number>(
  formula: Formula<T>
) => formula.fn(formula.arg);
```

[Read more about generic types here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: This is a good answer as long as OP doesn't ever really need a union type like the original `Formula`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4yDew), where `calc()` rejects an argument of type `Formula<()=>number> | Formula<number>`.

Comment: I think I am running into that problem.  If I want to make a list of formulas and evaluate them all (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaYxPN)), I can't assign a type to the list.

Comment: @EugeneWolffe if you need lists or some other use case, please [edit] your question so that the [mre] shows exactly the problems you're having so that answers can address them.  I'm happy to try working on stuff but preferably only after all necessary use cases are laid out in the question.

Comment: @jcalz I tried clarifying problem specification while keeping things minimal.  Your example shows exactly what I was trying to do, so if you have any suggestions to make the question clearer, please let me know.  Thanks :)

Comment: Is something like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) issue preventing TypeScript from allowing mapping a mixed list of Formulas?

Comment: No, I wouldn't think so, since you're not using conditional types here. But this is definitely a limitation of TS. Either you keep `Formula` a union and then you run into the lack of correlated union support [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) or you make it generic as shown above in which case you could find yourself hitting the lack of existentially quantified generics [ms/TS#14466](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  See [this code](//tsplay.dev/mMVeVW) for a full exploration. Mostly you'll want type assertions and helper functions and move on.

Comment: @EugeneWolffe I am happy to write any of this up as an answer... although writing *all* of it up would take a very long time I might not have available to me.  If you can find which approach in there seems promising to you, if any, I can maybe flesh it out.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks!  I'll take a look at those links and see what I can come up with.  From what you said, it sounds like I'll at least be able to write a type-safe wrapper around what I want even if I'll have to cast internally.